# Update product details across the associated products

Tags: magento2

I want to build a custom module to update product title and price in customizable options of a product when the main product details are updated in the magento 2 backend.

as shown in the below image i have SKU 1444 in anothers product customizable options so when i update SKU 1444 price it is not getting reflected in customizable options

[image]

Any idea how to do this. Is there a settings in magento backend to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In events.xml observe following event

```
<event name="catalog_product_save_after">
        <observer name="update_custom_option" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\UpdateCustomOption" />
    </event>
```

Observer code

```
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
 
class UpdateCustomOption implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_cacheTypeList;

    protected $_cacheFrontendPool;
 
    public function __construct( \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface $cacheTypeList, \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Pool $cacheFrontendPool
    ) {
        $this->_cacheTypeList = $cacheTypeList;
        $this->_cacheFrontendPool = $cacheFrontendPool;
    }
 
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $sku = $observer->getProduct()->getSku();
        $price = $observer->getProduct()->getPrice();
        $name = $observer->getProduct()->getName(); 
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $resource = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
        $connection = $resource->getConnection();
        $CPOptionTypeValue = $resource->getTableName('catalog_product_option_type_value');
        $CPOptionTypePrice = $resource->getTableName('catalog_product_option_type_price');
        $CPOptionTypeTitle = $resource->getTableName('catalog_product_option_type_title');
        $productOptionQuery = "update ".$CPOptionTypeValue ." as t JOIN ".  $CPOptionTypePrice ." as t1 JOIN ". $CPOptionTypeTitle . " as t2 on t.option_type_id = t1.option_type_id && t.option_type_id = t2.option_type_id SET t1.price = ".$price." , t2.title = '".$name."' where t.sku = '".$sku."'";
        $connection->query($productOptionQuery);
        $this->cleanCache();
        } 

    public function cleanCache(){
        $types = array('config','layout','block_html','collections','reflection','db_ddl','eav','config_integration','config_integration_api','full_page','translate','config_webservice');
        foreach ($types as $type) {
                $this->_cacheTypeList->cleanType($type);
                }
        foreach ($this->_cacheFrontendPool as $cacheFrontend) {
                $cacheFrontend->getBackend()->clean();
                }
    }       
    }
```